# publish winforms application without install

Tags: c#, winforms, publish

I've been creating winforms application for a while now, but i've never really published one to other people before.

Recently I started doing this but every time I publish my build, the user requires to de-install his current installation and install the new one.

**Is there any way to remove this, so I'll only have to send a .exe file which they can use without any form of installing?**

I've attempted to send the .exe file in the bin/debug/ but this only seems to work on computers where Visual Studio is installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your solution and set the `CopyLocal` to true for all projects, this will ensure that the `..\Bin` folder contains all the necessary assemblies for your program. Then just zip up the `..\Bin` folder, get it onto the client machine, and then unzip it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This does not provide the solution that I want sadly.

Answer (score 3):

1) Change from `Debug` to `Release` in Solution Configurations

[image: Solution Configuration]

2) Right click on your project and click rebuild

3) Go to your `bin=>Release=> app.publish` for your exe version

4) Copy over any required .dll files,any .config files and any other resource/image files you need from `bin=>Release` to `bin=>Release=> app.publish`.

Your app.publish folder should now contain all the files required to run your form, and can be copied or zipped up and send to anyone who needs to use it !

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) as an installation method. It even has a built-in auto-update, so you can publish your application to a web server, and all existing installations will download latests version automatically.

To configure ClickOnce go to corresponding tab in your project settings.

Comment: I prefer to remove any form of installation. What I wish to do is just copy a .exe file to the destinated computer and have it work.